# How to split a long HTML table into page-columns?

Tags: html

How can I split a long HTML table into as many **page columns** as needed to make **the entire table** fit as maximally as possible on the screen?

I'm not asking how to split a row, or column, or cell, but the **entire** table:

This code prints a long table that doesn't fit on the screen.

```
1:   | <table>
2:   | <tr><td>abcd</td></tr>
---cut-----------------------
200: | <tr><td>wxyz</td></tr>
201: | </table>
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| abcd | ijkl | qrst | yz.. |
| efgh | mnop | uvwx | .... |
+------+------+------+------+
```

I'd rather **not** hard-code it into the HTML code like this:

```
1:  | <table>
2: | <tr><td>abcd</td><td>ijkl</td><td>qrst</td><td>yz</td></tr>
3: | <tr><td>efgh</td><td>mnop</td><td>uvwx</td></tr>
4: | </table>
```

Comment: so you want to split your table horizontaly or verticaly? Splitting element(table) means that there will be 2 or more the same elements(table elements in your case). So what realy you want split and in what direction?

Comment: Why? For display purposes? What is wrong with `table width='100%'` for horizontal fit?

Comment: @Epsil0neR: Vertically. But hardcoding it will not do, since the number of rows is dynamically determined.

Comment: @jammykam: I'm not looking for horizontal fitting, but vertical splitting.

Comment: What is the number dynamically determined with? Whatever you're using (python, php, ruby, java, etc.) should probably be used to split it.

Comment: Ok, vertically makes more sense. How would you navigate the different pages of table data? Using pagination (1,2,3...)? What you are asking is very tough since each "page" could have a number of different rows, you would have to use JavaScript to determine the heights and which rows to include in each page. This would have to be on page load since if you hide content they no longer have any height.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should drop it. But it can't be that difficult. This is exactly what UNIX commands `ls` and `column` do.